# Kafka 2.12 Consumer Group (with command prompt) - Second consumer can't seem to receive the message?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am starting out with Apache Kafka 2.12 and I'm running into problems with practicing the Consumer Group while using the command prompt: When two consumers are created and set to subscribe to a topic in a group, only one consumer seems to receive all the message, the other consumer receive nothing.

So, after running the Zookeeper and Kafka Servers (imagine that we're starting fresh), this is what I typed on the 3rd command prompt to create the topic:

`kafka-topics.bat --create --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 2 --topic test-TOPIC`

Next, I opened the 4th command prompt and entered this:

`kafka-console-consumer.bat --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic test-TOPIC --group learning`

Finally, I opened the 5th command prompt and entered this:

`kafka-console-consumer.bat --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic test-TOPIC --group learning`

Now I go back to the 3rd command prompt and started entering these messages (separated with a new line):

```
One
Two
Three
Four
Five
Six
```

But only the 5th command prompt receive the messages. The 4th command prompt gets nothing. From the tutorial I see in the net, it worked as planned, yielding this result:

5th command prompt gets:

```
One
Three
Five
```

4th command prompt gets:

```
Two
Four
Six
```

So... where did I go wrong in this?

Answer (score 0):

Kafka does not guarantee even distribution of produced messages in a topic (for 6 messages, not each of 2 partitions gets 3 messages).

Therefore, if Six ends up in partition 1, for example, it's still working as intended - two consumers of the same group do not see the same messages. This is the only guarantee of consumer groups.

Also, around Kafka 2.7, all messages within one record batch will be sent all into one partition. (2.12 is currently not a valid Kafka release, this number refers to the Scala version the code is compiled from)

Comment: I see. What I downloaded was Kafka 2.12-3.4.0 . Which means, the Kafka version is 3.4, whereas the Scala is 2.12. The tutorial I was looking at used Kafka 2.12-2.3.0. In that case, are there still ways to ensure even distribution of produced messages for Kafka 3.4? If there isn't, then okay.

Comment: The version isn't really relevant. This is just how Kafka has always worked, despite changing to the StickyPartitioner, as mentioned around v2.7